# Does $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}(\int_{1/2}^{1-ε}＋\int_{1＋ε}^{3/2})\frac {\log x} {(x-1)^2} dx$ exist?

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Does $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}  \left(\int_{1/2}^{1-ε}＋\int_{1＋ε}^{3/2}\right)\frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2}  dx$$ exist?

Hint says $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \left( \frac{\log x-a-b(x-1)-c(x-1)^2}{(x-1)^3}\right)$$ exists only if $a=0,b=1,c=-\frac12$.

I have no ideal how to apply this hint.

Another way is also appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: $\log x \leq x-1$ on the given interval  $(1/2,3/2)$.

Comment: My hint for the problem would be: by the Taylor expansion of $\log x$ around $x=1$, there exists a continuous function $g : [1/2, 3/2] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\log x = (x-1) + (x-1)^2 g(x)$.

Comment: If you are ok, could you give me your answer too in the answer form ?

Comment: I guess it actually turns out in this particular case that you can explicitly do the integral by an integration by parts with $u=\log x$, $dv = \frac{dx}{(x-1)^2}$ and then follow up with an integration by partial fractions.  The strategies from the answers given so far should be more generally applicable, though, even in cases where an antiderivative can't be found in closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd introduce $x=1/u$ in the first integral $$\int_{1/2}^{1-\epsilon} \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} \, {\rm d}x = -\int_{1/(1-\epsilon)}^2 \frac{\log u}{(u-1)^2} \, {\rm d}u $$ so that
$$ - \int_{1/(1-\epsilon)}^2 \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} \, {\rm d}x  + \int_{1+\epsilon}^{3/2} \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} \, {\rm d}x \\
= - \int_{1/(1-\epsilon)}^{3/2} \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} \, {\rm d}x - \int_{3/2}^2 \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} \, {\rm d}x  + \int_{1+\epsilon}^{3/2} \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} \, {\rm d}x $$
and the integral clearly exists iff $$\int_{1+\epsilon}^{1/(1-\epsilon)} \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} \, {\rm d}x $$
will exist. You can use $1/(1-\epsilon) = 1 + \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)$ and then apply $\log x \leq x-1$ (the integral is clearly positive).

Comment: Your last improper integral converges to $0$, so the original limit exists. Is this right? Thank you so much. The hint in my question is meaningless?

Comment: I dunno, I didn't bother looking at it, since it seemed too complicated (while you can see it by taylor-expanding). Yes, the limit exists and goes to $0$, so the original integral equals the middle term.

Comment: Your  way is simple and seems better than the given hint.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Taylor expansion of $\log x$ around $x = 1$:

$$\log x = (x-1) - \frac{(x-1)^2}{2} + \frac{(x-1)^3}{3} - \frac{(x-1)^4}{4} + \cdots.$$

Therefore, there exists a continuous function $g : [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$g(x) = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{x-1}{3} - \frac{(x-1)^2}{4} + \cdots$$

such that $\log x = (x-1) + (x-1)^2 g(x)$.

Therefore,

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \left( \int_{1/2}^{1-\varepsilon} + \int_{1+\varepsilon}^{3/2} \right) \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} dx =
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \left( \int_{1/2}^{1-\varepsilon} + \int_{1+\varepsilon}^{3/2} \right) \left( \frac{1}{x-1} + g(x) \right) dx.$$

Now, if we split into the term for $\frac{1}{x-1}$ and the term for $g(x)$, in the first we get
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} (\log(1/2) - \log(\varepsilon)) + (\log(\varepsilon) - \log(1/2)) = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} 0 = 0.$$
In the second, setting $G$ to be an antiderivative of $g$ on $[1/2, 3/2]$ (and thus $G$ must in particular be continuous) and using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we get
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} (G(3/2) - G(1 + \varepsilon)) + (G(1 - \varepsilon) - G(1/2)) = \\ (G(3/2) - G(1)) + (G(1) - G(1/2)) = G(3/2) - G(1/2).
\end{align*}
Since both components of the sum have a limit, the sum must then also have a limit.  (In other words, the Cauchy principal value of the improper integral $\int_{1/2}^{3/2} \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2} dx$ exists.)